# Passing arguments to my function with do_action and add_action is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code and the $var1 arrives empty to my function i dont know why, i've tested declaring the variable inside the function and it does work but when i try to declare it outside the function and pass it as a parameter with the do_action it doesn't work, any insights on this ? thanks

The add_shortcode works fine

```
$name="link";   
    add_shortcode($name, 'aa_link_shortcode' );

    function shorcode_resources($var1) {
        global $post;
       $shortcode_found = false;

       if ( has_shortcode($post->post_content, $var1) ) {
          $shortcode_found = true;
       } 

       if ( $shortcode_found ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'core', ABS_URL . '/shortcode/css/flipbox.css' , false ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js',ABS_URL . '/shortcode/js/flipbox('.$var1.').js', false );
       }

}

do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $name);    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shorcode_resources', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Im triyng to pass the variable $var1 as an argument for the function shorcode_resources(), thanks for your comment

Comment: Where is $var1 declared?

Answer (score 0):

You can't `do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts');`It's wordpress inbuilt action.

Please have a look at below code snippet.

```
<?php 
function shorcode_resources() {

    $var1 = "link";

    global $post;
    $shortcode_found = false;

    if (has_shortcode($post->post_content, $var1)) {
        wp_enqueue_style('core', ABS_URL . '/shortcode/css/flipbox.css', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('my-js', ABS_URL . '/shortcode/js/flipbox(' . $var1 . ').js', false);
    }    

}

$name = "link";
add_shortcode($name, 'aa_link_shortcode');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shorcode_resources', 10);
```

Comment: But you are not passing the $var1 variable as an argument for the function shorcode_resources(), that's what i want to do, that's why i add the do_action() in the wordpress codex says is the way to pass arguments to a function on add_action, could you help me please, and thanks for your comment

Comment: wp_enqueue_scripts action do no accepts any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Malay Solanki is right, you shouldn't use `do_action` in this context. You need to scope `$var1` into your PHP function. (This is of course assuming `$var1` is declared somewhere in the script before this function... It's hard to give you an exact answer since you haven't provided enough code for context)

```
$var1 = 'foo';
$name="link";   
    add_shortcode($name, 'aa_link_shortcode' );

    function shorcode_resources() {
       global $post,$var1;
       $shortcode_found = false;

       if ( has_shortcode($post->post_content, $var1) ) {
          $shortcode_found = true;
       } 

       if ( $shortcode_found ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'core', ABS_URL . '/shortcode/css/flipbox.css' , false ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js',ABS_URL . '/shortcode/js/flipbox('.$var1.').js', false );
       }

    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shorcode_resources' );
```